# Embedded document index for date is not used

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I'm newbie using MongoDB and I have a collection for this type of document:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "coordinate" : {
        "latitude" : 532144,
        "longitude" : -33333
    },
    "margin" : "N"
},
"prices" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "GAS_95",
        "price" : 1370,
        "date" : ISODate("2014-05-03T18:39:13.635Z")
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "DIESEL_A",
        "price" : 1299,
        "date" : ISODate("2014-05-03T18:39:13.635Z")
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "DIESEL_A_NEW",
        "price" : 1350,
        "date" : ISODate("2014-05-03T18:39:13.635Z")
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "GAS_98",
        "price" : 1470,
        "date" : ISODate("2014-05-03T18:39:13.635Z")
    }
]
```

}

I need to retrieve the prices for specific date, so then I run this query:

```
db.gasStation.aggregate(
{ "$unwind" : "$prices"}, 
{ "$match" : { 
    "_id" : { 
        "coordinate" : { 
            "latitude" : 532144 , 
            "longitude" : -33333} , 
            "margin" : "N"
        } , 
    "prices.date" : { 
        "$gte" : ISODate("2014-05-02T23:00:00.000Z") , 
        "$lte" : ISODate("2014-05-03T22:59:59.999Z")
    }
}
```

});

All works fine, I retrieve the documents but I presume that my can be improved, I tried to create an index for _id and prices.date:

```
db.gasStation.ensureIndex( { 
    "_id" : 1,
    "prices.date" : 1
} )
```

After that I try to see if the index is being used in my query with the explain option but is not using any index:

```
{
"stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {

            },
            "plan" : {
                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                "allPlans" : [
                    {
                        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$prices"
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "_id" : {
                "coordinate" : {
                    "latitude" : 532144,
                    "longitude" : -33333
                },
                "margin" : "N"
            },
            "prices.date" : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2014-05-02T23:00:00Z"),
                "$lte" : ISODate("2014-05-03T22:59:59.999Z")
            }
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

}

is there any reason that my query is not suitable to use the index? I read on MongoDB documentation that the only pipeline that is not using indexes is $group but I'm not using that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-arranging your aggegration pipeline operators. For instance, this query:

```
db.gasStation.aggregate([
{ "$match" : {
    "_id" : {
        "coordinate" : {
            "latitude" : 532144 ,
            "longitude" : -33333} ,
            "margin" : "N"
        }
}},
{ "$unwind" : "$prices"},
{ "$match" : {
    "prices.date" : {
        "$gte" : ISODate("2014-05-02T23:00:00.000Z") ,
        "$lte" : ISODate("2014-05-03T22:59:59.999Z")
    }
}}

], {explain:true});
```

produces this output, which does show some index usage now:

```
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "_id" : {
                        "coordinate" : {
                            "latitude" : 532144,
                            "longitude" : -33333
                        },
                        "margin" : "N"
                    }
                },
                "plan" : {
                    "cursor" : "IDCursor",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "coordinate" : {
                                        "latitude" : 532144,
                                        "longitude" : -33333
                                    },
                                    "margin" : "N"
                                },
                                {
                                    "coordinate" : {
                                        "latitude" : 532144,
                                        "longitude" : -33333
                                    },
                                    "margin" : "N"
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : "$prices"
        },
        {
            "$match" : {
                "prices.date" : {
                    "$gte" : ISODate("2014-05-02T23:00:00Z"),
                    "$lte" : ISODate("2014-05-03T22:59:59.999Z")
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
```

The point is to try to get pipeline operators like $match and $sort up front at the beginning of the pipeline to use indexes to limit how much data is accessed and passed on into the rest of the aggregation. There is more that you can do with the above example to improve performance but this should give you a good idea of how to approach it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried and works like a charm! I just wondering if in this case is useful to use $elemMatch for improve the query a little bit. But I read that $elemMatch has some problems also with the indexes... My concern is if I have thousands of prices this query is not using any index on the price level and I don't know the performance if I run this query multiple times. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Im going to quote the docs on this:

> The $match and $sort pipeline operators can take advantage of an index
>   when they occur at the **beginning of the pipeline**.

source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes

You don't have a $match or $sort at the beginning of the pipeline, you have the $unwind operation. Thus, indexes are useless here.

**Edit** - detailed explanation:

Still, it is possible to move part of the matching condition to the beginning of the pipeline so that an index will be used.

```
db.gasStation.aggregate([
    { "$match" : {
        "_id" : {
            "coordinate" : {
                "latitude" : 532144 ,
                "longitude" : -33333} ,
                "margin" : "N"
            }
    }},
    { "$project": { "prices"  : 1, "_id" : 0 } },
    { "$unwind" : "$prices"},
    { "$match" : {
        "prices.date" : {
            "$gte" : ISODate("2014-05-02T23:00:00.000Z") ,
            "$lte" : ISODate("2014-05-03T22:59:59.999Z")
        }
    }}  
],{explain:true});
```

However, here this index is unnecessary:

```
{"_id":1, "prices.date":1}
```

Why? Because the $match at the beginning of the pipeline only filters by the _id. In mongodb a document's _id is automatically indexed, and that's the index that will be used on this case.

Also, you can further optimize your query by removing unnecessary fields using the $project operator. If you don't need a field, remove it as soon as possible.

Comment: Needs more elaboration. But technically correct. Forget what the documentation says about "optimization". The only optimization in the aggregation pipeline is the first statement for "removing fields that are not used elsewhere in the pipeline". Everything else mentioned is just useless coding hacks. I'd code them anyway. Better an more full explanation gets you more votes than the incorrect accepted answer. There's a badge to be awarded for that. Correct and let me know.

Comment: @NeilLunn you are right, there was a lot more to be said about the question. Just edited it to include a more detailed explanation. Thank you.